# I want to copy listview item on click to clipboard

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I want copy text from the list view item to clipboard when the user clicks the item but I am stuck at using clipboard within the onitemclick function. How can I implement the same?

```
public class SmsActivity extends Activity
  implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
  ListView a;

  String[] c = { "Anniversary SMS", "Best Luck SMS", "Birthday SMS", "Broken Heart SMS", "Education SMS", "Emotion SMS", "Exam SMS" };


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    a = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView));
    a.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.title, c);

    a.setAdapter(adapter);


  }

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: I want to copy the text of the list view item to clipboard when the user click on the list item

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer will be help full to you

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt, long 
   String s =  a.getItemAtPosition(position)
   ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
   ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label",s);
   clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first Get value of Clicked item then put into clipboard

```
String clickdData=(String) paramAdapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);   

    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
     ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", clickdData);
     clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

import this package
**android.content.ClipboardManager** and NOT **android.text.ClipboardManager**

Comment: unable to resolve label here

Comment: check my updated ans